# Unable to sort values in ascending order in bar graph python

Tags: python, pandas

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt`


# creating the dataset
data = pd.read_csv('agemode.csv')
data.columns = data.iloc[9]
data_new = 
    data.drop([0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33], 
    axis=0).dropna(axis='columns').sort_values(by=['Below 30 Years'], ascending=False)
    data_new
```

[image: The column "Below 30 Years" is sorted incorrectly]

Comment: I bet you have strings, not numbers. Convert to numeric.

Answer (score 0):

Into your method

```
.sort_values(by=['Below 30 Years'], ascending=False)
```

add the parameter `key=lambda col: col.astype('int')`:

```
.sort_values(by=['Below 30 Years'], ascending=False, key=lambda col: col.astype('int'))
```

---

*The explanation:*

You want to sort that column by the *numerical* order, **not** by the *lexicographic* (dictionary) order.